# How can I add a removable disk (USB drive) boot option in my BIOS boot option menu?

Tags: bios

The DVD drive on my HP Pavilion a1509in (Intel P4) is not working. To install any OS I have to use my USB drive.

In the BIOS boot options menu it shows only:

> Floppy disk
>   CD/DVD drive
>   Hard disk drive

I've checked everywhere in the advanced setup menus to see how to enable a USB boot option but I can't find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many workarounds on my PC I just found the another way to boot from a USB disk drive, using some open source tools:

- Install Easy BCD.
- Add the ***Eacy BCD BIOS extender*** entry to the boot menu.
- The Easy BCD BIOS extender menu redirects to **plop boot manager** if you choose the boot option during boot up.
- Now you have the option to boot from a USB disk drive as shown below:

  [image]

This will be helpful for many old computers which do not support USB boot in their BIOS.

Comment: Ah, I guess we were assuming you didn't currently have a bootable OS. +1

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing.  frustrated I was searching around for answers...but I figured it out.

the usb drive is listed under the HD not removable drives.

selected the HD option, then moved the USB to the top

made sure it was first in the boot option

rebooted and whola!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that model doesn't support USB boot.  You might want to try upgrading the BIOS to see if it helps, but the latest bios dates back to 2007 and doesn't suggest it provides this feature.

The USB drive might appear as a disk, so if there is an F button you can press during bootup to select a boot device you may be able to see it.

[HP Drivers Page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3355576)

Comment: @peter Is there anyway to trick my Floppy drive boot option as a USB drive ?

Comment: No.  I think your best bet would be a new IDE cdrom drive